# CASES and Ouput with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select certain records with cases from multiple tables and I need to select them based on some cases that I will create.

This is what I have so far for my query:

```
select distinct top 10  
        QuestionTag =( CASE 
                    WHEN qt.id = 98 THEN 'Save the Sale TP'
                    WHEN qt.id = 99 THEN 'Close the Loop'
                    WHEN qt.id != 98 AND qt.id != 99 THEN ''
                    WHEN qt.id = 98 AND qt.id = 99 THEN 'Save the Sale TP'
                END),
        c.contactid as contactid, c.first, c.last,
        st.datecomplete, st.ownerIdfk, st.finalScore, st.surveyid,
        cc.clientcontactid, cc.leadsource,
        se.eventdate, se.ProcedureName, se.LocationName, se.salesperson, se.SpecialistName, st.surveyname
        from sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st
        join sigweb.dbo.survey_types_main stm on st.surveyid =  stm.surveyidfk      
        join sigweb.dbo.contact c on st.contactid = c.contactid
        join survey.dbo.client_contacts cc on c.contactid = cc.contactidfk
        join survey.dbo.survey_events se on c.contactid = se.contactidfk 
        join survey.dbo.results r on r.owneridfk = st.owneridfk
        left join survey.dbo.questionsAdmin qa on qa.questionidfk = r.questionidfk
        join survey.dbo.QuestionTags qt on qt.id=qa.tagidfk
```

This is part of the output:

```
QuestionTag             ContactID               First   Last  
-----------             ---------               -----   ----  
                        2012082911569010000001  John    Reardon 
Close the Loop          2012082911569010000001  John    Reardon 
Save the Sale TP        2012082911569010000001  John    Reardon                               
                        2012082911569010000003  Beverly Conley 
Close the Loop          2012082911569010000003  Beverly Conley 
Save the Sale TP        2012082911569010000003  Beverly Conley  
                        2012082911569010000009  Larry   Grigsby     
                        2012082911569010000011  Brenda  Bain    
                        2012082911569010000012  Richard Pecora  
                        2012082911569010000018  Karl    Oliszczak
```

I need to add a "where" to select only one of the duplicate records based on these cases:

IF a contactid has only CTL then select that 
IF a contactid has only STS TP then select that 
IF a contact appears more than once and it has '' and CTL and STS TP then output only the STS TP
IF a contact does not have CL or STS TP then do not output the contact at all.

I was thinking that I need to add one more case inside my WHERE clause but I was wondering if there is another method that will save me time and code writing

Comment: What are these CTL, STS TP etc?

Comment: CL = Close The Loop, STS = Save The Sale. You can see them on my output

Comment: `WHEN qt.id = 98 AND qt.id = 99` isn't likely to happen.  You'll at least need to have another join, or correlated subquery, to puzzle out the question tags that apply to a given contact, then analyze that set for the specific patterns you want.

Comment: @HABO Yes I realized that after I posted my question. What I meant there is IF an ID exist with both CL and STS then select STS

Comment: does it make sense to add a where clause, 'where qt.id in (98,99)?  from your conditions, it looks like those are the only times you want contacts output

Comment: it does but it won't do what I need it to do.

Comment: how's that?  or how is your description of what you need to do missing that requirement?

Comment: well if I add a list with options it will still output all possibilities. I need to output only certain records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my improved attempt. It does what it is supposed to do but it is kind of slow.

```
        select 
        qt.questiontag, qt.id,
        c.contactid as contactid, c.first, c.last,
        st.datecomplete, st.ownerIdfk, st.finalScore, st.surveyid,
        cc.clientcontactid, cc.leadsource,
        se.eventdate, se.ProcedureName, se.LocationName, se.salesperson, se.SpecialistName, st.surveyname
        from sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st
        join sigweb.dbo.survey_types_main stm on st.surveyid =  stm.surveyidfk      
        join sigweb.dbo.contact c on st.contactid = c.contactid
        join survey.dbo.client_contacts cc on c.contactid = cc.contactidfk
        join survey.dbo.survey_events se on c.contactid = se.contactidfk and st.surveyid = se.surveytypeidfk
        left join survey.dbo.questiontags qt on 
            (select top 1 qa.tagidfk
            from survey.dbo.results r
            join survey.dbo.questionsadmin qa on r.answeridfk = qa.answeridfk and (qa.tagidfk = 98 or qa.tagidfk = 99)
            where st.owneridfk = r.owneridfk
            order by qa.tagidfk ) = qt.id
        where st.datecomplete > '2013-02-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
;with cte as (
 select QuestionTag =( CASE 
                        WHEN qt.id = 98 THEN 'Save the Sale TP'
                        WHEN qt.id = 99 THEN 'Close the Loop'
                        ELSE ''
                      END) ,
                     --Other_List_of_Columns,
                     row_number() over(partition by c.contactid order by 
                       case when qt.id = 98 then 1 
                            when qt.id = 99 then 2
                       else 3 end) rn
  From your_list_of_tables
)
select top (10) * from cte where rn = 1 and QuestionTag <> ''
```

Comment: This is really close to what I need. The participation part I don't really understand what it does except sorting

Comment: You mean `partition`? it groups the data by c.contactId and then give row numbers in the given order by list.

Comment: when will qt.id = 98 AND qt.id = 99??

Comment: yeah that one I took out @Beth. Btw If I set rn=2 i get both save the sale and close the loop outputs. Didn't that suppose to return only 99 which Close the Loop?

Comment: :) I moved the `And` bit of the `case` from bottom to top but didn't notice that it was same id he was checking. thanks man @Beth. Answer updated. I think it works for your conditions now. Also you can alter the case statement in row_number() ordering to get different out puts. Important thing is that it is doable..

Comment: Thanks Kaf. I found another way of doing it but I will try your method as well because mine is a bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you need something more like this, unless your requirements are different from what you've posted:

```
SELECT
    datecomplete, ownerIdfk, finalScore, surveyid, surveyname, contactid
    CASE WHEN max_questionSort = 98 THEN 'Save the Sale TP' ELSE  'Close the Loop' END AS questionTag,
    c.contactid AS contactid, c.FIRST, c.LAST,
    cc.clientcontactid, cc.leadsource,
    se.eventdate, se.ProcedureName, se.LocationName, se.salesperson, se.SpecialistName
FROM
    (SELECT 
        datecomplete, ownerIdfk, finalScore, surveyid, surveyname, contactid
        MAX(QuestionSort) AS max_questionSort 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            CASE 
                    WHEN questionidfk = 98 THEN 1
                    WHEN questionidfk = 99 THEN 0
            END AS QuestionSort ,
            datecomplete, st.ownerIdfk, finalScore, surveyid, surveyname, contactid
        FROM 
            sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st INNER  JOIN 
            survey.dbo.results r ON 
            r.owneridfk = st.owneridfk
         WHERE
            questionidfk IN (98,99)) w 
    GROUP BY
        datecomplete, ownerIdfk, finalScore, surveyid, surveyname, contactid) st INNER JOIN 
        JOIN sigweb.dbo.contact c ON st.contactid = c.contactid
        JOIN survey.dbo.client_contacts cc ON c.contactid = cc.contactidfk
        JOIN survey.dbo.survey_events se ON c.contactid = se.contactidfk
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a CTE that provides the question id's for each contact.  Then use that in your larger query to pick the appropriate rows.

```
; with ContactQuestions as (
  select ContactId, QuestionId,
    case when qt.id = 98 then 1 else 0 end as STSTP,
    case when qt.id = 99 then 1 else 0 end as CTL
    from many_joined_tables ),
  ...

where case
  -- Only STSTP.
  when STSTP = 1 and not exists ( select 42 from ContactQuestions where ContactId = c.ContactId and CTL = 1 ) then 1
  -- Only CTL.
  when CTL = 1 and not exists ( select 42 from ContactQuestions where ContactId = c.ContactId and STSTP = 1 ) then 1
  -- Multiple rows for a contact and they have CTL and STSTP then output the STSTP row.
  --   Since only CTL or STSTP can be set for a single row this is equivalent to checking for
  --   any CTL row and the current row being STSTP.
  when exists ( select 42 from ContactQuestions where ContactId = c.ContactId and CTL = 1 ) and STSTP = 1 then 1
  else 0
  end = 1
```

Comment: @GeoNicolaidis - You have to select _something_ in an `exists` query, but what you select is immaterial.  Many people use `*`, whilst others rant against _ever_ using a wildcard select.  I use 42 as a placeholder that let's me know that I don't actually care about the value, I simply needed to fill the space to meet syntax requirements.  Why 42?  It is the [answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).